# How to select shell language with a MUI Office 2010 install using OCT file

Tags: deployment, microsoft-office-2010, languages

I have created a network installation point for Office 2010 ProPlus that contains two language packs — en-us, and cs-cz (Czech). I've also created an Office Customization File.

In my environment the OS language is English, however the locale is set to Czech. Office 2010 setup when run from the network installation point keeps running with Czech as the shell UI language. This behavior is documented.

I attempted to modify the `config.xml` file in the `ProPlus.WW` directory and add the following two lines:

```
<AddLanguage Id="en-us" ShellTransform="yes"/>
<AddLanguage Id="cs-cz" />
```

When I run `setup.exe /adminfile myconfig.msp` the setting is ignored. When I try to specify the config file on the command line like `setup.exe /adminfile myconfig.msp /config ProPlus.WW\config.xml` setup just displays the set of available command-line options, apparently not accepting these two parameters at once.

So, how to override this behavior and force English to be the default shell UI language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem is in the order of command line arguments. The `/config` argument must be specified first, **before** the `/adminfile` argument. Then the setup behaves as expected, installing the language marked with `ShellTransform="yes"` as the display language.

The command-line will look like this:

```
setup.exe /config ProPlus.WW\config.xml /adminfile myconfig.msp
```

---

*Workaround used before:* Most likely there's no way to do that which is a **very, very annoying** “feature”. The only workaround is:

1. change Windows' locale in Regional settings to wanted primary language;
2. install Office 2010;
3. change back Windows' locale to the secondary language.

Answer (score 1):

```
SETUP.EXE /CONFIG CONFIG.XML /ADMINFILE SOME-MSP.MSP
```

Take note: Office MUI product ID is OMUI.xx-xx. Visio = VISMUI.xx-xx and Project MUI = PMUI.xx-xx. It must be set in your first line: Configuration Product="OMUI.nl-nl"

example of customized CONFIG.XML:

```
<Configuration Product="OMUI.nl-nl">
<Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
<Logging Type="Verbose" Path="C:\TEMP" Template="MS-Office-OMUI.NL-NL.TXT" />
<AddLanguage Id="nl-nl" ShellTransform="yes"/>
<AddLanguage Id="nl-nl" />
<Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="Never" />
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as soon as I will be doing any installs.